# Data com IONIC e angulaJS e firebase

Tags: ionic

Bom dia, estou pegando a data do firebase para o IONIC com auxílio do angular e estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:
Error parsing date: "1531595027828". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: Por favor, cole seu código para entendermos de onde está vindo o erro.

Comment: a recomendação é que utilize o pipe do angular para realizar a transformação ou parse e não utilize o parse no javascript, mas manda trecho do seu código para ser mais preciso com a orientação